# helm install a chart and give parameters to the depencie chart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, memcached, helm

I am trying to use the chart `stable/mcrouter` for memcache sharding, everything works, but this chart uses a memcache chat as dependencie.

I would like to know if I can pass parameters to memcache chart, this is the dependencies file: requirements.yaml

```
dependencies:
- name: memcached
  version: 1.2.1
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  condition: mcrouter.memcached.enabled
```

mcrouter chart url: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mcrouter

In few words, I can give parameters to mcrouter, but I cannot give parameters to memcache chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review this [official article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-memcached-on-kubernetes-engine). It provide good example:

```
helm install stable/mcrouter --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=3
```

Other examples:

```
helm install stable/mcrouter --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=3 --set memcached.resources.requests.memory=512Mi

helm install stable/mcrouter --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=15 --set memcached.resources.requests.memory=10Gi --set memcached.resources.requests.cpu=2 --set memcached.memcached.maxItemMemory=8432
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way, I downloaded `stable/mcrouter` with:

```
cd /tmp && helm fetch stable/mcrouter --untar
```

Now under `/tmp/mcrouter/charts/memcached/templates` you have the memcached templates and you can check the accepted parameters

I found if you use `helm install stable/mcrouter --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=3` works, because `memcached.replicationCount` is part of the mcrouter chart.

If you want to pass parameters to the subchart, you need to use:

```
helm install --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=2 --set memcached.memcached.resources.requests.memory=100M --set memcached.memcached.maxItemMemory=100 stable/mcrouter
```

Or you can edit the `values.yaml` of the subchart under `/tmp/mcrouter/charts/memcached/values.yaml`

Now you can install the chart with the news parameters:

```
cd /tmp/mcrouter && helm install --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=2 .
```